# Test for both errors and "other" values

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, error-handling, idataerrorinfo

I am currently using MVVM and `IDataErrorInfo` to validate input in my `TextBox`es in a simple data entry app. I currently mark the `TextBox` with a red background if the user enters a non-number:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, I would like to also give a visual indicator (orange background?) if the entered value is a valid input but "out of spec" or similar. What are my options for multiple "error validation" types?

[using .NET Framework 4.5.1]

Comment: Not really.  IDEI only returns strings, so you'd have to encode some additional info, alter the visual on the encoded metadata using one converter, and then use a different converter to get the message.  It's a bit wonky, but with a couple different converters, you could swing it.  Hacky, but quick.  You might, alternatively, hook into the validation system and modify it to use a different flavor of data error interface.  I've never done it, but if I tried, I'd have to delve into the source to see how it works and where I might be able to get into the validation pipe.

Comment: @Will thanks. I just happened upon ``INotifyDataErrorInfo`` - does that contain (explicit) facilities to do what I want?

Comment: No.  Again, the errors returned from the interface are strings.  You can't extend strings, so you can either hook into validation in the UI somehow and use a different validation interface of your design, or use converters and encode metadata about the errors into the string somehow.

Comment: @Will the Converters on the Property Values worked nicely. Hacky, but quick, as you mention. :)

Comment: Hey, add details to an answer below and you can close this out.

Comment: @will I was sorta hoping for a better soln to come along, but maybe that's not happening. If you want credit you can write up the answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Meh, I didn't really do anything.  Your solution may help others.  I really doubt a better solution will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the suggestion by @Will.  I inserted a single character at the beginning of each `IDataErrorInfo` error string (in this case, all I needed was 2 options, so I used "0" and "1").   I created 2 `IValueConverter`s; one for each of the Background and ToolTip properties:

```
public class WarningErrorBkgdConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        char firstChar = ((string)value)[0];
        if (firstChar == '0')
        {
            return Brushes.Pink;  // Error
        }

        Debug.Assert(firstChar == '1', "CANTHAPPEN: Expecting 1st char of string to be 1, was " + firstChar);
        return Brushes.Gold;  // Warning
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}



public class WarningErrorTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Just ignore the error code
        return ((string)value).Substring(1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I modified the `TextBox` Style from the original question to incorporate  these converters:

```
<local:WarningErrorBkgdConverter x:Key="warningErrorBkgdConverter"/>
<local:WarningErrorTextConverter x:Key="warningErrorTextConverter"/>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                Converter={StaticResource warningErrorBkgdConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent,
                Converter={StaticResource warningErrorTextConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then in my `IDataErrorInfo` implementation, a sample usage:

```
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        uint testUint;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "YieldPsi1":
                if (YieldPsi1 == "")
                    return null;

                if (!UInt32.TryParse(YieldPsi1, out testUint))
                    return "0Must be a number";

                if (testUint < 42000)
                    return "1Out of spec";

                return null;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works well!